# ¿Cómo proceso varios ficheros con Awk y añado un salto de línea tras leer cada uno de ellos?

Tags: linux, script, awk

Tengo varios archivos en varios directorios tipo:

- /home/yo/1/config/1.conf
- /home/yo/2/config/12.conf
- /home/yo/hola/config/126.conf

Y dentro de estos tengo información que se repite como:

```
Host: XXXXX 
IP: 192.16.X.X 
Memoria: 1024
```

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me arroje la información en el siguiente formato:

```
Host    IP    Memoria
XXXXX 192.16.X.11 1024
XXXXX 192.16.X.12 3096
```

He intentado con el comando awk de la siguiente manera:

`awk 'BEGIN { printf "%8s\t %4s\t %8s\n", "Host", "IP", "Memoria"} /Host/ || /IP/ || /Memoria/ { printf "%10s\t", $2}' /home/yo/*/config/*.conf`

Pero el resultado es una sola línea separada por tabulaciones.

Quisiera que cada que termina de leer un archivo realice el salto de línea, de pronto alguien pueda darme una guía de como hacerlo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como vas añadiendo tabulaciones después de cada fichero, Awk no sabe cuándo poner un salto de línea que delimite el fin de un fichero y el inicio del siguiente.

Para hacer esto, y si usas GNU Awk, tienes la opción de tirar de [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html), que es un bloque de texto que se puede ejecutar al terminar de leer un fichero (igual que `END` al terminar de leer el último). Por tanto, simplemente di algo así como:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "%8s\t %4s\t %8s\n", "Host", "IP", "Memoria"}
     /Host/ || /IP/ || /Memoria/ { printf "%10s\t", $2}
     ENDFILE{print ""}' *conf
```

Comment: excelente, funcionó muy bien, había intentado con ENDFILE pero lo estaba usando mal